The number of ways a pack of 52 cards can be divided among four players in 4 sets, three of them having 16 cards each the fourth just 4 card is
First player can get $16$ cards in $_{52}C_{16}$ ways  Second player can get $16$ cards in $_{36}C_{16}$ ways  Third player can get $16$ cards in $_{20}C_{16}$ ways  Fourth player can get $4$ cards in $_{4}C_{4}$ ways  But the first three sets can be interchanged in $3!$
Required number of ways $\large= \frac{_{52}C_{16} \times _{36}C_{16} \times _{20}C_{16} \times _{4}C_{4}}{3!}$
I don't understand why we divided by $3!$.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773

The rules are not clear.  I would have thought that,  as individuals are distinct,  it mattered who got what hand.  Is that your intent here?

You need to clarify the rules.  It's customary in problems like this to assume that individuals are always distinguishable.  Of course, you don't need to assume that but either way you should be clear about what you are assuming.

If you have to assign 16 cards to A, 16 cards to B, 16 to C, and 4 to D, there are $$ {_{52}C_{16} \times _{36}C_{16} \times _{20}C_{16} \times _{4}C_{4}} $$
ways of doing that, as your intuition was probably suggesting.
If you instead consider the problem of simply splitting the deck into 4 subdecks of 16, 16, 16 and 4 cards (without labeling or assigning an order to them), you can do that in
$$ \frac{_{52}C_{16} \times _{36}C_{16} \times _{20}C_{16} \times _{4}C_{4}}{3!} $$
different ways. You can convince yourself of this because after splitting the deck into subdeks, there are exactly $3!$ ways of assigning the subdecks to A, B, C, D with the restriction I said above: there is one way of giving D the only deck with 4 cards, while the other 3 remaining subdecks can be assigned to A, B, C in 3! different ways.
So, as you stated the problem, the correct answer would be
$$ {_{52}C_{16} \times _{36}C_{16} \times _{20}C_{16} \times _{4}C_{4}}. $$
If you read the problem in a book or somewhere, it is possible that it was stated slightly differently and it is actually something that resembles my second example. Sometimes it is a bit tricky to understand what probability problems want you to compute, one needs to get used to it.
